# The shortest path between multiple points using Manhattan distance

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, optimization

This is one of the assignments I got in school. Any kind of advice will be greatly appreciated.

I have a map of streets, where each crossroads is represented with coordinates = tuple of whole numbers (x, y). The length between two coordinates is equal to **Manhattan's distance** between them. I am taxi driver and I have **coordinates for each customer** and **coordinates where they want to go**, starting coordinates and **maximum number of customers I can have in the car**. I need to find the shortest path to drive all my customers to their destination. The customer can exit the vehicle only at their end destination. **The result** is sequence of the customers, in which the taxist has to pick / drop them.

My current solution uses recursion to find all their paths, compare their length and return the shortest one. The problem is, that it's too slow. It needs to be done in under a sec.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT1:
The function: **taxi** = current taxi coordinates, **starti** = pick up coordinates of all customers (starti[0] = pickup coordinates for customer 1), **cilji** = end destinations of all customers (cilji[0] = drop coordinates for customer 1), **left** = number of customers left to drive to their destinations, **index** = just to make the end result, **n** = max numbers of customers in the taxi, **atm** = the number of customers in the car at that moment

```
public static int abs(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return -n;
    }
    return n;
}
public static int razdalja(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return abs(a[0] - b[0]) + abs(a[1] - b[1]);
}

public static int[] fun(int[] taxi, int[][] starti, int[][] cilji, int left, int m, int index, int n, int atm) {
    int[] temp1;
    int[] temp2;
    int[] tab = new int[m*2+1];
    int[] min = new int[m*2+1];
    min[m*2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    if (left == 0) {
        return tab;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {

        if (starti[i] != null && atm < n) { 
            temp1 = starti[i];
            starti[i] = null;

            tab = fun(temp1, starti, cilji, left, m, index+1, n, atm+1);
            tab[index] = i+1;
            tab[m*2] += razdalja(taxi, temp1);
            starti[i] = temp1;

            if (tab[m*2] < min[m*2]) {
                min = tab;
            }

        } 
        else if (cilji[i] != null && starti[i] == null) {
            temp2 = cilji[i];
            cilji[i] = null;

            tab = fun(temp2, starti, cilji, left-1, m, index+1, n, atm-1);
            tab[index] = i+1;
            tab[m*2] += razdalja(taxi, temp2);
            cilji[i] = temp2;

            if (tab[m*2] < min[m*2]) {
                min = tab;
            }

        }



    }

    return min;
}
```

Example of an input

```
6                      //max customers in car
148,128                //taxi starting coordinates
7                      //number of customers
1,45,199,178,69        //first customer startX,startY,endX,endY
2,54,87,26,83          //and so on...
3,197,147,135,93
4,12,49,61,66
5,91,8,55,73
6,88,42,15,9
7,184,144,31,34
```

And the correct output for the input above (my function return table of these numbers + last number in the table is the length of the path)

```
7,3,1,2,6,5,6,7,4,2,5,4,3,1

this means:
pick (customer) 7  (184,144)
pick 3             (197,147)
pick 1                ...
pick 2
pick 6
pick 5
drop 6
drop 7
pick 4
drop 2
drop 5
drop 4
drop 3
drop 1
```

EDIT2:
Even more, I noticed something I could probably improve, but I'm not sure how. That for loop in the function, always iterates through all i-values, even though in a lot of cases it does nothing untill it reaches high enough "i", since starti[i] and cilji[i] both equal null for most of the i-values, once we get deep enough in recursion. For each already delivered customer there is one iteration that does nothing.

---

This is how the tree for two customers look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3irL.png
The circled coordinates are where the taxi drops a customer (i forgot to circle one, it's obvious).

```
input:
2
5,5
2
1,3,7,5,7
2,9,2,9,7

output:
1,1,2,2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your solution and maybe someone has suggestions on how to refactor or make it more efficient

Comment: That's basically the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with a few additional nitpicks. There are a few algorithms that deliver good approximations, but otherwise the problem is NP-hard.

Comment: You mentioned you need to execute it under a second, in that case, can you also share the constraints on the coordinates and the number of customers? What's their possible max value?

Comment: @nellex Added the hardest input (at least I think it's the hardest).

Comment: What is your grid size? I assume it's `200x200` because the largest coordinate I  see is `199`. The function `razdalja` is missing. Does your current solution work [even if it is too slow]? Do you have [and can post] the correct/expected output for a given input?

Comment: @CraigEstey Gird size is not given. I can only assume that the largest is 200x200. (in all the test inputs I got, not one coordinate is bigger than 200) The function razdalja just calculates the Manhattans distance. I added it now, sorry. I've also added the expected output for a given input under the code. Thanks!

Comment: @CraigEstey Also, my current solution works. But for some inputs, I let it run for more than 10 mins and it still didn't give an output, so I terminated it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the correct output you posted. (e.g.) If the taxi picked up passenger 1 as its first stop, I'd expect to see the output start with: `45,199`. In the general case, you may need an "operation" struct that splits a passenger into two "taxi operations" (e.g. `@45,199,pickup,1 ... @178,69,dropoff,1`. This is because you may have two [or more] passengers departing from the same destination and you only pick up one of them because the taxi only has space for one of them

Comment: @CraigEstey The output is the sequence, in which the taxist picked/dropped the customers. Therefore, in the given output, this means: pick customer 7, pick customer 3, pick customer 2 ... I'll add it to the post. When the id of the customer repeats, it means he dropped him.

Comment: @CraigEstey  I've also splited the pickup coordinates into tab **starti** and drop coordinates into tab **cilji**. Which means starti[0] = pickup coordinates for the first customer, cilji[0] = drop coordinates for first customer and so on...

Comment: Got it [re. output]--that's fine. My guess is that you need the equivalent of a tree/graph. The root of the tree is the taxi initial position [at level 0]. It will have 7 children. For each child [at level 1], each will have 6 children. At level 2, each child will have 5 children. And, so on ... I think that traversing this tree would minimize redundancy of the search. With some cleverness, it can be scanned on the fly without actually precreating the nodes [just a recursive stack that is 7 deep] and a picked up bitmap and a dropped off bitmap

Comment: @CraigEstey That's what I did, kinda. But the tree doesn't always split like you said. I'll add how the picture for 2 customer looks like.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've formulated a dynamic-programming based solution which runs under ~ 0.17s for your hardest test case: https://ideone.com/lKUql9

```
INF = 100000000000

pickup = {}
dest = {}
trace = {}
dp = {}

def calc(a, b):
    return abs(a[0] - b[0]) + abs(a[1] - b[1])

def solve(curPos, completed, ongoing):
    if len(completed) == N and len(ongoing) == 0:
        return 0
    curState = (curPos, frozenset(completed), frozenset(ongoing))   

    if curState in dp.keys():
        return dp[curState]

    minVal = INF
    for i in pickup.keys():
        if i in completed: continue
        newOngoing = ongoing.copy()
        newCompleted = completed.copy()

        if i in ongoing:
            newOngoing.remove(i)
            newCompleted.add(i)
            val = calc(curPos, dest[i]) + solve(dest[i], newCompleted, newOngoing)
            if val < minVal:
                minVal = val
                trace[curState] = \
                    ("drop " + str(i), (dest[i], newCompleted, newOngoing))
        elif len(ongoing) < maxCustomers:
            newOngoing.add(i)
            val = calc(curPos, pickup[i]) + solve(pickup[i], newCompleted, newOngoing)
            if val < minVal:
                minVal = val
                trace[curState] = \
                    ("pickup " + str(i), (pickup[i], newCompleted, newOngoing))

    dp[curState] = minVal
    return minVal

def path(state):
    stateVar = (state[0], frozenset(state[1]), frozenset(state[2]))
    if stateVar not in trace.keys():
        return
    print (trace[stateVar][0])
    if trace[stateVar][1] != None: 
        return path(trace[stateVar][1])

maxCustomers = int(input())
rstr = input().split(",")
start = (int(rstr[0]), int(rstr[1]))
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    line = input().split(",")
    pickup[int(line[0])] = (int(line[1]), int(line[2]))
    dest[int(line[0])] = (int(line[3]), int(line[4]))

print("Total distance travelled: ", solve(start, set(), set()))
path((start, set(), set()))
```

The code in many terms is self-comprehendible but I'm willing to explain things more in detail if something isn't clear.

Edit:

We define our current state to be the current coordinates where we are (curPos), the set of trips which we have already completed (completed) and the set of trips which is still in progress i.e. we have the customers in the car (ongoing) - any trip out of these two sets haven't been started yet. I use a `frozenset()` because python dictionaries doesn't allow using `set()` as a part of the hash key for the dictionary (i.e. a Map, `dp` and `trace` in our case) and hence ordinary `set()` must be converted into an immutable set that is `frozenset()`

There are multiple over-lapping subproblems which are the main reason we use dp. You can add a `print ("Dp Hit: ", curState)` whenever curState exists in `dp.keys()`, like I've done: https://ideone.com/mKFsVH (produces runtime error due to too many output lines). As you can see memoization handles large many cases which we don't need to re-explore. To understand better consider reading about using dynamic-programming for traveling salesman problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/

`if i in completed` is ~ O(log(n)) lookup since set internally are implemented as self-balancing binary trees, and yes, the mere condition `if len(completed) == N` should be sufficient enough. Had just added the other half as a sanity check.

Comment: I've got a few questions, since i'm not used to Python. So you've got **curState** in which you save curPos and completed and ongoing sets frozen; this just means that these two sets are immutable, right? And then you check if **curState**, so a sequence of curPos, completed set, ongoing set already exists in **dp**? I don't understand why would this ever happen, I mean, the sets can be the same, but the distance shouldn't be? Also, I wonder how long does the "**if i in completed**" takes, cause I wanted to implement that into my code, but that would take a for loop through whole array?

Comment: Also, is the "if len(completed) == N and len(ongoing) == 0" really needed? Wouldn't just one of them be enough?

Comment: @Blarc yes we define our current state to be the current coordinates where we are (curPos), the set of trips which we have already completed (completed) and the set of trips which is still in progress i.e. we have the customers in the car (ongoing) - any trip out of these two sets haven't been started yet. I use a `frozenset()` because python dictionaries doesn't allow using `set()` as a part of the hash key for the dictionary (i.e. a Map,  _dp_ and _trace_ in our case) and hence ordinary `set()` must be converted into an immutable set that is `frozenset()`.

Comment: @Blarc there are multiple over-lapping subproblems which is the main reason we use dp. You can add a `print ("Dp Hit: ", curState)` whenever curState exists in `dp.keys()`, like I've done: https://ideone.com/mKFsVH (produces runtime error due to too many output lines). As you can see momization handles a large many cases which we don't need to re-explore. To understand better consider reading about using dynamic-programming for travelling salesman problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/

Comment: @Blarc `if i in completed` is ~ O(log(n)) lookup since set internally are implemented as self balancing binary trees, and yes, the mere condition `if len(completed) == N` should be sufficient enough. Had just added the other half as a sanity check. I hope things would be clear now.

Comment: @nelIex I figured out my code was pretty much the same as yours. The only difference is, that you add memoization, for which I still don't completely understand how it works, since path 9,2 - 9,7 - 3,7 is not the same as 9,2 - 3,7 - 9,7 for example.

Comment: @Blarc think about it in terms of our state variable. Say we have 4 trips to process, and we've completed two of them and now are at a point (x, y). Say they two trips we've completed are indexed as 1 and 2, then our state {(x, y) [1, 2] [ ]} and {(x, y) [2, 1] [ ]} share the same common sub-problem of how we handle the 3 and 4 indexed customer starting from (x, y). This is because it doesn't matter in which order we completed the trips until we're at the same position. The same logic can be extended to our ongoing trips list. Implementation wise, for a set, [1 2] and [2 1] is the same.

Comment: Any idea how to make this memoization in Java?